# ffmpeg: why 2 video stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm on ffmpeg 6.

Take a video then:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 00:01:09 -t 20s -i "video.mkv" -map 0:0 -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" "output_reference.mkv"`

then:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "output_reference.mkv" -map 0:0 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 25 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" "output_test_01.mkv"`

Why **output_test_01.mkv** has 2 video stream inside?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`-map 0:0` leads to inclusion of one stream, `-filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"` leads to another. The filter_complex does NOT operate upon the initially mapped stream. Mapped video streams are operated upon by `-vf` or `-filter:v`.

See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection
especially 4.1.2, 4.1.3 and the last set of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How can I solve my problem? I need only 1 video stream on output  using "-filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" " (to sync the frames btw input and ouput files)

Comment: Change `-filter_complex` to `-vf`

Comment: Thanks, another solution is remove "-map 0:0"